# Jquery change fadeOut / In to fadeTo

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a smooth background-image transition, right now I have this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

var initialBg =  $('#apDiv1').css("background-image");

var firstTime = true;
var arr = ["url(bg-0.jpg)", "url(bg-1.jpg)"];
    (function recurse(counter) {
        var bgImage = arr[counter];
        if (firstTime == false) {
            $("#apDiv1").fadeOut(700, function(){
                $('#apDiv1').css('background-image', bgImage);
            });
            $("#apDiv1").fadeIn(700);
        } else {
            firstTime = false;
        }               
        delete arr[counter];
        arr.push(bgImage);
        setTimeout(function() {
            recurse(counter + 1);
        }, 6600);
    })(0);      
});
```

But this creates some kind of a dead spot where there's a half second without any background image.

I've tried changing to `fadeTo`, but couldn't really figure out how to make the change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To cross fade, you'll need two elements.

Comment: I see, could you tell me why for example this: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/hYEzV/ does a smooth transition (also using fadeOut and fadeIn) isn't that basically the same as what I have, just that I am doing it with the background image ?

Comment: I think that you need to preload the images. In the jsfiddle example the images are loaded because exists previusly in DOM.

Comment: That fiddle has three elements (images) cross fading, you're fading one single element out, replacing the background, and fading it in. You can't fade two images into each other with just one single element.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense I guess. So would this work the same way if I had another div with the 2nd background image in it, and fading that one in and the 1st one out ?

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, I went with the 2 div approach and that looks and works beautifully !

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it will work for you:

```
$(window).load(function(){

var initialBg =  $('#apDiv1').css("background-image");

var firstTime = true;
var arr = ["url(bg-0.jpg)", "url(bg-1.jpg)"];
    (function recurse(counter) {
        var bgImage = arr[counter];
        if (firstTime == false) {
            $("#apDiv1").fadeTo(700, 0.1, function(){
                $('#apDiv1').css('background-image', bgImage);
            });
            $("#apDiv1").fadeTo(700,1);
        } else {
            firstTime = false;
        }               
        delete arr[counter];
        arr.push(bgImage);
        setTimeout(function() {
            recurse(counter + 1);
        }, 6600);
    })(0);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place de fadeIn into the call back?

And as said in comments, the effect would be better with 2 divs fading in/out at the same time.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var initialBg =  $('#apDiv1').css("background-image");

    var arr = ["url(bg-0.jpg)", "url(bg-1.jpg)"];
    $("#apDiv1").fadeOut(700, function(){
          $('#apDiv1').css({'background-image' : arr[1]});
          $("#apDiv1").fadeIn(700);
        });    
    });
```